# Can two triangles not be congruent but five elements in triangle are same

Tags: triangles

---

> Can two triangles not be congruent but five elements in triangle are
> same

---

There are 3 sides and 3 angles in triangle. All 3 sides and 3 angles are collectively called 6 elements

Comment: What's an element?

Comment: An 8-12-18 triangle and a 12-18-27 triangle share all three angles and two sides.

Comment: Are you still here, Adi? Any observations on the comments and/or the answer that has been posted?

Comment: Yes answer helped

Comment: You have the option of "accepting" my answer, by clicking in the check mark next to it. But if you still need some clarification, you should tell us what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that by "elements" OP means side lengths and angles.

Let triangle $ABC$ have sides $AB$ of length $8$, $BC$ of length $12$, and $AC$ of length $18$. Let triangle $XYZ$ have sides $XY$ of length $12$, $YZ$ of length $18$, and $XZ$ of length $27$.

Then the triangles are similar, since $|AB|/|XY|=|BC|/|YZ|=|AC|/|XZ|=2/3$.
So $\angle A=\angle X$, $\angle B=\angle Y$, and $\angle C=\angle Z$.

Also, $|BC|=|XY|=12$, and $|AC|=|YZ|=18$. So, five elements are equal, but the triangles are manifestly not congruent.